# Powering Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Multiple Attachments: Recommendations for Portability

Tags: hardware, wireless, battery, power-management, alternative-power

Ok so I'll try and keep this short and sweet. Basically, I have all these attachments for my Raspberry Pi 3B+

1. [Raspberry Pi 7" Touchscreen](https://www.microcenter.com/product/645934/mcm-electronics-7-pi-touchscreen-lcd-display)
2. [Case for Touchscreen w/ Cooling Fan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08VSFB6F5)
3. [Raspberry Pi Camera Module V2-8 Megapixel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01ER2SKFS)
4. [Raspberry Pi Sense Hat](https://www.microcenter.com/product/453920/raspberry-pi-sense-hat)

and I'm running the latest Bullseye OS on a 32GB SD card. As you can imagine the "Not Enough Power" message just lives on my screen but everything; except the camera, works fine with what I use it for. I really only program on it but I wanna start using it as a laptop!

So my 1st question is, I am kinda tired of that lack of power message and just came across 'Power Boards'. After reading a bit I think their purpose is just to be able to supply Raspberry Pies with that extra power to allow for multiple attachments like I have... I believe? I listed everything I have because I don't know how I would go about finding how much power would be needed to power all my things efficiently(of course from what I've read this doesn't seem plausible but at least better would be nice). If anyone knows more about this stuff and would like to recommend some power boards that could work for me would be great! Also if possible I would love to learn more about these things so if teaching me anything about this stuff would be great. I could definitely be completely wrong about the use of these things so teaching & helping me out would be great!
(Ex. I think this [power board](https://www.makerfocus.com/products/dockerpi-power-board-20w5v-4a-power-supply-with-cooling-fan-infrared-remote-control?variant=31319578837069) works?? I don't know what would be too much power though and what I would need to look for or consider!)

Finally 2nd and last question; but as I previously said I think I could really benefit from making this thing transportable so am wondering if I could add a rechargeable battery into this thing and if I can then how to go about doing that. I understand it might not be possible just because of how much I have but am staying hopeful! Again teaching me anything about this stuff would be greatly appreciated! (Ex. I assume a [battery pack](https://www.makerfocus.com/collections/raspberry-pi/products/makerfocus-3-7v-lipo-battery-10000mah-lithium-rechargeable-battery-9065115-with-micro-ph2-0-plug-for-raspberry-pi-ups-board) like this would be what I would need. It looks as though it comes with a board that connects power to the Pi and the board is also how I power up the battery. I just don't know how this would work if I have the power board as well.)

If you read all of this thank you so much and recommending me things to get to make this happen would be amazing! :)

Comment: It would help us to help you if we knew how much current you were using at what voltages. Without that we can only guess and over size it to be safe. Since you are considering a battery how long do you want it to operate on battery. Remember batteries lose performance as they age so that needs to be considered when sizing the battery. Per the specs, a Raspberry Pi 3B+ needs a power supply capable of delivering 5.1 volts DC at 2.5 amps: 12.75 Watts. Note 1.2A is allocated for the USB.

Comment: Awesome thanks for your response and walk-through Gil! Currently I'm using my sisters iPad charger which is labeled as a "USB Power Adapter" at 12W so it appears I'm just under. I also just tried an even bigger brick which had this on the label {It has 4 ports} USB-A:5V=3A/5V=4.5A/9V=2A/12V-1.5A/4.5V=5A(22.5W Max) and this one also gave me the low power message. Is that the info you were looking for or were you more so referring to using a multimeter? Gotcha so with the battery you're implying get more power so age hits the sweet spot right? Just cause I'm cautious 10hrs seems legit!

Comment: Nope! Those numbers have to be bigger then the actual load which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Please keep the question to ONE question, multiple questions in one question is flagged and removed.